# NoClassDefFoundError Could not initialize class <com.my.application.package>.EMF Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, backend

Newbie at using GAE as a backend for my Android app and I get this exception.
I navigated to `http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/explorer`, found my Endpoint and made a request using one of my methods. But no matter what method I call i get this error. Any clues as to what it might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding the following line to the persistance file:

`<property name="datanucleus.singletonEMFForName" value="true"/>`